# A general statement

Tags: grammar

I would like to make a general statement:

**The first statement about work places:

1. In work places, **the** employees must respect their director.
2. In work places, **the** employees must respect their directors.

Is it correct if I remove "the" here:

3. In work places, employees must respect their director.
4. In work places, employees must respect their directors.

**The second statement is about the way you pay the bill:

1. when paying by card, the customer**s** just have to hand out a small card to the cashier**s** instead of counting a pile of bank notes before giving to them.
2. when paying by card, the customer just has to hand out a small card to the cashier instead of counting a pile of bank notes before giving to them.

Is it correct if I remove "the" here?

3. when paying by card, customers just has to hand out a small card to cashiers instead of counting a pile of bank notes before giving to them.

=====
My questions for 2 statements:

1. Which sentences are correct?
2. What is the difference between the correct sentences.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, you generally must have an article, "the" or "a", before a singular noun. (Sometimes other adjectives eliminate the need for the article, like if you say "my" or "one".) Plurals do not require an article. Sometimes we put "the" in front of a plural to indicate we are talking about some specific group, but it's not required grammatically. Like you might say, "Songs make me feel cheerful." No "the", so songs in general. You might also say, "This album contains many songs by composer Fred Smith. The songs make me feel cheerful." The "the" here indicates that we are talking about a specific set of songs, namely, those by Fred Smith that are on this album, and not about songs in general.

In your first pair of sentences, you appear to be talking about all employees in any work place, so "the" is not necessary. It is not wrong here because it could be interpreted to mean "the employees who are in work places", as opposed to other kinds of employees. Employees working from home, perhaps? But if we think of all employees as being in some sort of work place, you could include "the" or not and it doesn't really change the meaning.

In the second set of sentences, if you say "the customers" that presumably means the customers identified by context, perhaps the customers using credit cards or whatever sort of cards you're talking about. Depending on the context, if you don't say "the" it may be clear that you are talking about customers using credit cards. Or it may mean that all customers must use cards and their is no other option. Which I don't think is what you mean. So again, the "the" is basically optional. Without it, the set of customers is probably still clear from context.

Whether you say "customers have to" or "the customer has to", either is valid. Arguably there could be an ambiguity either way. If you use the plural, someone might suppose you mean that all customers share the same card. If you use the singular, someone might suppose you mean that there is only one customer. But in this case, I'd think it's obvious from context that neither of those is what you mean. I presume you mean that each customer has his own card. If there really was possibility ambiguity, you could reword the sentence a little to make this clear.

Couple of side notes:

In sentence 3 you say "the customers just has to". But "customers" is plural and "has" is singular, so this is incorrect. It should be "the customers just have to".

In 1, 2, and 3, "counting a pile of bank notes before giving to them" is awkward. "Give" is usually transitive, that is, you should say what you are giving. Obviously you mean "counting a pile of bank notes before giving THE BANK NOTES to them", but the grammar is incorrect if you leave that out. If you put it in the sentence sounds repetitious. So you should say, "counting a pile of bank notes before giving the cash to them" or using some other synonym for "bank notes". Or in this case, I would just leave it out and say "... counting a pile of bank notes."

Comment: According to your explanation, this means that these 2 sentences have the same meaning:
(1)Employees working from home are lazier than employees working in the office. (Without “the”)
(2) The employees working from home are lazier than the employees working in the office. (With “the”)

Comment: “the” is not really important in writing about all things of a type. Right?

Comment: In my 2nd example. You said I could reword the sentences to make them clear. Is it correct if I fix the sentence as following: when paying by card, the customers just has to hand out small cards to the cashiers instead of counting a pile of bank notes before giving to them. (I put the word "customers, cards, cashiers in to plural form);

Comment: @LEHANH RE lazier: Yes. There is, of course, a minor grammatical difference, but in this case it makes no difference to the meaning because you've spelled out what the two groups are that you're talking about.

Comment: @LEHANH If I understand what you're trying to say, yes. When used with a plural, "the" only makes a difference if you are distinguishing all things of that type (no "the") with only the things previously identified in the context (use "the"). For example, "Some of our employees work from home. The employees who work from home are lazier." vs "... Employees who work from home are lazier." With "the", you are saying that you are only talking about a subgroup identified in context, in this case, employees of our company. Without "the", you mean all employees who work from home.

Comment: @LEHANH RE correction: 1. If you use "customers", plural, you must use a plural verb, "have", instead of "has". As I mentioned above, you should have an object after "giving", like, "... counting a pile of bank notes before giving the cash to them" or "counting a pile of bank notes before giving them to the cashiers", etc. (I wouldn't say "... before giving them to them" because two "thems" is confusing.)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, Jay

Comment: Suppose I am an owner of a company, I want to make a statement about my employees, both are correct. Right?

(1) The employees who works from home are more lazier than the employees who work in the office
(2) Employees who works from home are more lazier than employees who work in the office

Comment: There are two issues with your sentences not related to your question. 1. "Employees" is plural so takes the plural verb "work" rather than the singular verb "works". "The employees who work from home ..." 2. "More lazier" is redundant. The "-ier" ending indicates a comparison. You can say "Bob is lazy", or "Bob is lazier than Sally". But you can't say "more lazier" because lazier is already a comparison. You could say "more lazy". All that said, yes, whether you include the "the" or not, either way is correct.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, I have 2 sentences talking about my perspective in general:(1) In my opinion, as I see , employees working from home are lazier than employees working in the office. (Without “the”) (2) In my opinion, as I see ,the employees working from home are lazier than the employees working in the office. (With “the”). The difference with "the" emphasize that employees belong to a group of people who work from home or in the office. The version without the doesn't have this emphasis. Is it right?

Comment: @LEHANH Yes, that's correct. In your example, because you qualify "employees" with "working from home" or "working in the office", it's clear that in each case you don't mean all employees. So saying "the employees" to indicate that you don't mean all is not necessary. It's legal, it doesn't hurt, but it doesn't really change the meaning.

Comment: Similarly, How about these general sentence: (1) (The) People who eat a lot of sugar are fat. (2) Generally, I don't like (the)people who drink. These 2 sentences both work with and without "the" as a general statement. Right?

Comment: @LEHANH Both are grammatically valid with and without the "the". The meaning could be different in context. "People who eat a lot of sugar are fat" means all people who eat a lot of sugar. "The people who ..." means, of the people identified in context, those who eat a lot of sugar, etc. Like if you said, "We did a study on weight gain involving 100 test subjects. The people who eat ..." In that case "the people" would mean the people in the group identified in context, namely, the people in our study. "who eat a lot of sugar" would then further restrict it ...

Comment: ... to just those members of the study who eat a lot of sugar.

Comment: so Why with my sentence in previous post : "(1) In my opinion, as I see , employees working from home are lazier than employees working in the office. " You answered ""the employees"==> It's legal, it doesn't hurt, but it doesn't really change the meaning.", this means that I still can use "the" for this sentence, although this is just a general statement. Right? But this sentence only refers to employees in general , not specific employees identified in a context (in my office, or in my city, in a survey... etc). Right? But why is there difference with sugar example?

Comment: could you please help me with this post?

Comment: @LEHANH In general, the-plus-plural means some specific group within the larger group. Usually this group will be made clear by context. A plural without "the" means all members of the named group. If you are talking about employees in general, if nothing in context indicates you are specifically talking about employees of a certain company or employees with red hair or whatever, then there is no subset for "the" to limit us to, so saying "The employees who work from home ..." must mean all employees who work from home. If you had started out talking about employees who work for your ...

Comment: ... company, then "the employees who work from home" would most likely be understood to mean, of the group of employees previously identified, namely, those who work for this company, those employees who work from home. But if you just said "Employees who work from home", that would mean all employees who work from home. We might expect you to then tie this to employees who work for your company.

Comment: You said "If you are talking about employees in general, if nothing in context indicates you are specifically talking about employees of a certain company or employees with red hair or whatever, then there is no subset for "the" to limit us to, so saying "The employees who work from home ..." must mean all employees who work from home===> This means that when we want to mention to a group of employees who work from home IN THIS WORLD  (not employees in a specific place), we still can use "the" here. Right?

Comment: Because my native friend tell me that when I refer to a group of people IN THE WORLD (in general meaning), I can't use "the". I can only use "the" when I refer to a group of people in a specific place (such as in my company). So that, I always in confusion about this matter.

Comment: For example, native speakers often say this is a wrong sentence when I refer to a group of employees in the world (in general).  (1) Normally, employees who work from home are lazier than employees who work in the office. If I add "the" here, people would say this is a wrong sentence.

Comment: @LEHANH The general rule is, if you want to say "all of them in the world", don't use "the". If you are limiting discussion to some subset, which generally should be made clear from context, use "the". I think I confused you by bringing up a special case. The special case is, If there is nothing in context to limit the subset, then adding "the" or not doesn't change the meaning. But if this is confusing you, don't worry about it. Just follow the general rule: All in the world: no "the". Some subset: "the".

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience to me.

Comment: I think I confused you by bringing up a special case. The special case is, If there is nothing in context to limit the subset, then adding "the" or not doesn't change the meaning.==> can you please give me a context or an example which is a special case as you said?

Comment: @LEHANH If you began a conversation by saying, "Employees of this company are lazy. The employees who work from home are especially lazy", that would NOT be an example of the special case I am mentioning. By saying, "The employees", you are limiting it to the subset of employees specified by the context, namely, employees of this company. But if you began an conversation by saying, "The employees who work from home are lazy", you have not established any context for a subset, so by "the employees" you would be understood to mean the subset given in the current sentence, namely, employees ...

Comment: ... who work from home. That's the special case I'm talking about. Third case: If you began a conversation by saying, "The employees are lazy", listeners would wonder which employees you are talking about, as you have not identified any subset, either in previous sentences or the current sentence.

Comment: If I was an owner of a company, I would complaint to  my friend:" (The) employees of my company are lazy. What should I do now?"
Both versions with and without "the" have the same meaning. Right?

Comment: @LEHANH Both are grammatically correct and both mean the same thing. In practice, most Americans would use "the" there but I can't think of a rule why.